# LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted! after removeFromParent()

Tags: c++, c, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I have a test.c file which has this function call:

```
functiontest(2,x);
```

I would like to delete this function call (with an llvm pass) and when I try to use **removeFromParent()** function like this:

```
calledFunction1->removeFromParent();
```

this causes LLVM to produce the following error:

> Referencing function in another module!
>    call void @functiontest(i32 2, float %tmp15)
>
> LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!

I also tried calling **eraseFromParent()** but this triggers an assert:

> Assertion `use_empty() && "Uses remain when a value is destroyed!"' failed.

I would prefer to use **removeFromParent()**

Any ideas what's wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it would be really helpful if you could post a minimal code sample that demonstrates your problem. Otherwise, we can only guess. Some observations though:

1. Why do you prefer `removeFromParent`? The call instruction has to be deleted too, that's what `eraseFromParent` does.
2. Did you call `replaceAllUsesWith` before erasing/removing? Otherwise, uses stick around.
3. Did you remove the function or the call instruction? This may explain the first error message.

Comment: i would like to remove only this call not the function

Comment: @strayrebel: right, but I'm not sure you're doing the right thing there. The error message from the LLVM verifier suggests that the ownership is broken. That's why it would be best if you could *reduce* your problem to a *minimal* code sample and show it

Comment: hmm yes sure , i was not doing the right thing probably. Maybe, i could better try erase the instruction which calls the function only.